# lyx export to pdf indent

Tags: pdf, lyx

I wrote a LYX file. On lyx it looks fine, that the way I want it to look like.
When exporting it, there is an indent that I don't know how to fix.
[in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWObp.png)
[in lyx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb92O.png)

Comment: I must be looking at the wrong thing: to me, it looks like the figure is more indented in the LyX output than the PDF output.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that in LyX the image can be seen as the complete image on the sheet but it seems that for the PDF format the image is too large.

To determine the size of the image that will be displayed in the PDF, click on the image and a Graphics tab will appear. In this it will say Output size, reduce the scale (ie. 70%, 50%) and click Apply.

Alternatively, you can also reduce the size to which the image will be displayed in LyX. In Graphics there is a LaTeX / LyX Options sub-tab, there you can change the scale at which the image is displayed in LyX